# Assign plugin to Element in typo3

Tags: typo3, frontend

Question:

lets say, I have this layout:
(There might be a markup-error, but that is not the most important part)

```
<div class="helpmaincontainer">
    <div class="w-clearfix helpnavi">
        <div class="language">
            <f:format.raw>{language_menu}</f:format.raw>
        </div>
        <div class="w-clearfix helptext"><a class="sitemap" href="#">Sitemap &nbsp;|&nbsp;</a><a class="sitemap" href="#">&nbsp;Impressum</a>
         </div>
         <f:format.raw>{indexedSearch}</f:format.raw>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, i include some "variables", which i fill in my typoscript.

for my case, the indexedSearch isn't working.

my typoscript looks like this:

```
indexedSearch =< lib.searchbox

lib.searchbox = COA
lib.searchbox {
    plugin.tx_rzautocomplete_pi1
}
```

But nothing appreas in my frontend.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

That should be

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.searchbox"/>
```

see http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/8-Fluid/5-using-typoscript-for-rendering-the-cobject-viewhelper.html